# SQL: Extract specific text from column into new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of tweets, that has a text column with the text of the tweet.
These tweets often have urls in them. I would like to extract the url if one is there into a new column, so i can make queries based on it.

Example:

```
text:                                               Url:
look at this cool picture someimagehost.com/abcd    someimagehost.com/abcd
```

How would i do that?

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: No HTTP in front of your URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching for hours how to do it with regexp and get the matching expression and finding nothing i saw the suggestion of using string functions. Here is the solution i came up with

```
UPDATE lsir_twitter_tweets as tweets
SET url = CASE WHEN LOCATE("http", tweets.text) = 0
THEN " "
WHEN LOCATE(" ", tweets.text, LOCATE("http", tweets.text)) = 0
THEN SUBSTRING(tweets.text, LOCATE("http", tweets.text))
ELSE SUBSTRING(tweets.text, LOCATE("http", tweets.text), LOCATE(" ", tweets.text, LOCATE("http", tweets.text)) - LOCATE("http", tweets.text))
END
```